# What is the isomorphism in: $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

*Disclaimer..*

*I know it's a very common, very basic, baby problem but I really had no idea how to google it.

So I'm asking here, while apologizing, for a link, reference, or short explanation.*

What is the isomorphism in:
$$\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_3\cong\mathbb{Z}_6$$
(and is it a ring morphism)?

Comment: Yes, it's a ring isomorphism. This is a very special case of the Chinese remainder theorem. It's easier to define the map that goes the other way first.

Comment: Oh ok so this **is** precisely the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural homomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z \\
n&\longmapsto(n\bmod2,n\bmod3)
\end{align}
has kernel $6\mathbf Z $, hence induces an isomorphism:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z  &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/32\mathbf Z \\
n\bmod6&\longmapsto(n\bmod2,n\bmod3)
\end{align}
The inverse isomorphism can be defined in terms of a *Bézout's identity*: if $2u+3v=1$ is such a relation, say $-2+3=1$, the inverse isomorphism is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z  \\
(a\bmod2,b\bmod3)&\longmapsto 2ub+3va\bmod6 \enspace(=3a-2b\bmod6)
\end{align}

Comment: "hence induces an isomorphism" because both sides have the same number of elements.

Comment: Rather because the kernel is  $6\mathbf Z $. The isomorphism does not rely on the finiteness of the ring: it is valid for the abstract Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: It is not immediately clear that the natural homomorphism is surjective.

Comment: It uses *Bézout's identity*. Have you solved simultaneous congruences? Another argument is an inverse map is given.

Comment: @Bernard: That is so simple with the kernel 6Z, thank you!!! :)